# How do I only print one row of an excel sheet from csv data?

Tags: python

[example I want to print all data in the row of 2009](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re3dm.png)

Comment: This information is not sufficient to adequately answer this question. Have you already tried something? Are you sure that 2009 is unique in that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the file using csv reader. Then you would iterate line by line before you find the line you're looking for. `row[0]` translates to the first column of the row.

```py
import csv

file_path = "name_of_your.csv"
with open(file_path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "2009":
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can do this using pandas like:

```
import pandas as pd

path = "csv path"
file = pd.read_csv(path)

print(file[file["Year"] == 2009])
```

This will give the desired the output.